Change Azure Portal color depending on resource subscription
We recently experienced an Ops guy changing settings on a production resource rather than a testing resource by mistake.
While our naming convention of resources include an environment abbreviation in the name and have tags, our architect don't want to enforce locks as only a strict select few have access to our production subscriptions.
Is it possible to change the background color or the top bar color in the Azure Portal depending on which subscription I'm viewing a resource in, to give a visual cue?
It is common practice on e.g. Virtual Machines to have a red desktop background color when you access a Production VM.
I wonder if that is possible in the Azure Portal somehow? I know it's possible in the developer portal.

Azure Portal doesn't support changing the background or top bar color based on the subscription you're viewing. To visually distinguish production resources, consider using browser extensions like Stylus to apply custom CSS, or enforce stricter naming conventions and subscription tags to make the environment more obvious.
